# Get the local cached Image Uri which is using Q42.WinRT Nuget Package in Windows Phone 8.1 C#

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am already binding q42controls:ImageExtensions.CacheUri in XAML.

Now how to get the cached image as a string/Uri value in C#.

Just by passing the Server Uri link I need to get local cached Uri link.

Comment: why? the advantage of solutions like this is that you do not have to think about the local uris at all

Comment: Actually I wanted those local uri which are cached to be used in Live Tiles and Secondary Tiles so I can point to local uri images

Answer (score 0):

It's an attached property, so just use the static getter and then ask the webcache:

```
var uri = ImageExtensions.GetCacheUri(yourImageElement);
var localUri = await WebDataCache.GetLocalUriAsync(uri);
```